# string compare with decimals

Tags: batch-file, decimal, string-comparison

What I'm trying to do is keep Shockwave up to date on multiple computer.  I've written this little batch script but its not working.  When it finds shockwave it will tell me they either dont have a version or that the version is newer.  Of course I believe it has something to do with the Decimals in both numbers but I'm not entirely sure??

```
:Check_Ver
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\Adobe\\Shockwave 12\\uninstaller.exe'" get version /format:list'
) DO SET "RESULT=%%I"

ECHO %RESULT%
IF /I %RESULT% GTR 12.2.4.194 GOTO :NEWERVERSION
IF /I %RESULT% EQU 12.2.4.194 GOTO :CORRECTVERSION
IF /I %RESULT% LSS 12.2.4.194 GOTO :OUTDATEDVERSION
```

Comment: What does `wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\Adobe\\Shockwave 12\\uninstaller.exe'" get version /format:list` output when ran from cmd?

Comment: Since you are comparing version numbers with dots in them which are not valid numerical figures, `if` will do string comparison, so the first pair of different characters of the compared strings define the result, so for instance `1.2.12` is less than `1.2.3`...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "result=12.2.4.194"
ECHO %RESULT%
CALL :CONVERT results %result%
ECHO %results%

CALL :CONVERT resultv 12.2.4.194

ECHO compare %result% to 12.2.4.194

IF /I %RESULTs% GTR %resultv% ECHO(GOTO NEWERVERSION
IF /I %RESULTs% EQU %resultv% ECHO(GOTO CORRECTVERSION
IF /I %RESULTs% LSS %resultv% ECHO(GOTO OUTDATEDVERSION


CALL :CONVERT resultv 1.2.4.194

ECHO compare %result% to 1.2.4.194

IF /I %RESULTs% GTR %resultv% ECHO(GOTO NEWERVERSION
IF /I %RESULTs% EQU %resultv% ECHO(GOTO CORRECTVERSION
IF /I %RESULTs% LSS %resultv% ECHO(GOTO OUTDATEDVERSION

CALL :CONVERT resultv 12.10.4.194

ECHO compare %result% to 12.10.4.194

IF /I %RESULTs% GTR %resultv% ECHO(GOTO NEWERVERSION
IF /I %RESULTs% EQU %resultv% ECHO(GOTO CORRECTVERSION
IF /I %RESULTs% LSS %resultv% ECHO(GOTO OUTDATEDVERSION

GOTO :EOF

:CONVERT
SETLOCAL 
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%a IN ("%2") DO (
 SET /a resulta=1000+%%a
 SET /a resultb=1000+%%b
 SET /a resultc=1000+%%c
 SET /a resultd=1000+%%d
)
endlocal&SET "%1=v%resulta%.%resultb%.%resultc%.%resultd%"
GOTO :eof
```

This routine should solve the problem.

The idea is to convert the version string to a leading-zero-filled string before making the comparison.

The `:convert` routine simply breaks its second parameter into 4 parts and adds 1000 to each part, yielding a 4-character result, then strings the 4 separate substrings together prefixed with an arbitrary "v". It's done withing a `setlocal/endlocal` bracket to keep the environment clean

The main part tries 3 different version numbers for deomnstration purposes. Depending on how you interpret the destination label chosen (and simply displayed using `echo`) it appeared to work happily for me ("newer" meaning that the proposed version is newer than the installed version in `%result%` - simply change the comparators to give what appears more logical - installed version is ??? than the nominated version)

Comment: i wasn't sure if batch could even successfully compare a 16 length string

Answer (score 0):

In batch/command prompt, a decimal point causes the comparison to be seen as a string, in which case `gtr` lss` fail. What you could do is convert the version compared and received to a flat integer right after your for loop

```
:: turn the for loop's return value to an integer, replace all "." with ""
set "result=%result:.=%"

:: Then, change your fixed version "12.2.4.194" [assuming it's a static value]
:: to "1224194" and compare using your if commands.
```

---

New script [Not noting what @CristiFati mentioned]:

```
:Check_Ver
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
    'wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\Adobe\\Shockwave 12\\uninstaller.exe'" get version /format:list'
) DO SET "RESULT=%%I"

ECHO %RESULT%

set "result=%result:.=%"
IF /I %RESULT% GTR 1224194 GOTO :NEWERVERSION
IF /I %RESULT% EQU 1224194 GOTO :CORRECTVERSION
IF /I %RESULT% LSS 1224194 GOTO :OUTDATEDVERSION
```

---

Side note:
Doesn't affect anything, but the `/I` flag isn't needed for integer comparisons, and the commands themselves don't need to be capitalized, no difference but just easier on the eyes.

Comment: lets say the version I'm comparing is something like this : 12.0.0.41940.  Then what happens is that it thinks 12.0.0.41940 is the greater number which its not.  So its false.  How do I get around that??

Comment: lets say its comparing 2.7.0.1948 and 21.0.0.176.  Its going to say that 2.7.0.1948 is greater then 21.0.0.176.  That is false, so this is only going to work %90 of the time or at least till I get through those updates, lol.

Comment: @travissimo Well i wasnt sure of the max string length of each version tape. Say if each string was a max 3 digits long, use a script to get the length, `if lss 4`, then add `4-strLength` zeroes to the front of the version number. Batch may run into an error comapring intigers this high, but I'm sure VBScript could handle that easily. As well, you run into the sensibility, what sane dev would make over a thousand, or even a hundred updates before moving to a higher bit. Or go with @Magoo's answer, which i really have to start stalking him and taking notes.